# Vault - How to store comma separated values or array using CLI

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I want to store the comma-separated values like a list of IP addresses into Hashicorp Vault. I am using Consul as the backend for storage. Please let me know is it possible or not? If yes! let me know how to implement it.

Example scenario

IP = "125.2.4.1,122.56.3.2"
(OR)
IP = [125.2.4.1, 122.56.3.2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store arbitrary text into Vault, so sure!

If you just set the value as `"125.2.4.1,122.56.3.2"`, then you can pull that same string out again later. You will simply have to interpret it as a list in your end-use case, whatever that might be.

```sh
$ vault kv put secret/ips ip="125.2.4.1,122.56.3.2"

Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2020-07-06T23:20:03.250328Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          1

$ vault kv get secret/ips

====== Metadata ======
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2020-07-06T23:20:03.250328Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          1

===== Data =====
Key        Value
---        -----
ip         125.2.4.1,122.56.3.2

$ vault kv get -field=ip secret/ips

125.2.4.1,122.56.3.2
```